# How to groupby().transform() to find mode in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, mode

I have a dataframe like:

```
lst = [["High", "A"], ["High", "A"], ["High", "B"],["Medium", "A"], ["Medium", "B"], ["Medium", "C"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =["Class", "Grade"])
```

I need to get the mode (majority vote) of "Grade" in each "Class".
If it's a tie vote, assign "x".

Below is what I expect to get:

| Class | Grade | Majority_vote |
| --- | --- | --- |
| High | A | A |
| High | A | A |
| High | B | A |
| Medium | A | x |
| Medium | B | x |
| Medium | C | x |

This is my code:

```
df['majority_vote'] = df.groupby(['Class'])['Grade'].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
```

I think the code will return 'nan' if it's a tie vote. Then, I will change 'nan' to 'x' later.

However, what I get is below:

| Class | Grade | Majority_vote |
| --- | --- | --- |
| High | A | A |
| High | A | A |
| High | B | A |
| Medium | A | A |
| Medium | B | A |
| Medium | C | A |

At class "Medium", the code returns the 1st element ("A") instead of 'nan'.

Any other method is appreciated.
Could you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with using `x.mode()[0]` is that `pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C']).mode()` evaluates to `['A', 'B', 'C']`. Meanwhile, `pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'B']).mode()` evaluates to `['A']`.

Here is a function that will return the mode (if there is only one) and "x" if there is a tie (i.e., multiple modes).

```py
import pandas as pd
lst = [["High", "A"], ["High", "A"], ["High", "B"],["Medium", "A"], ["Medium", "B"], ["Medium", "C"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["Class", "Grade"])

def get_mode_or_x(series):
    mode = series.mode()
    if mode.size == 1:
        return mode[0]
    return "x"

df.loc[:, "majority_vote"] = df.groupby("Class")["Grade"].transform(get_mode_or_x)
```

| index | Class | Grade | majority_vote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | High | A | A |
| 1 | High | A | A |
| 2 | High | B | A |
| 3 | Medium | A | x |
| 4 | Medium | B | x |
| 5 | Medium | C | x |